# What is the equivalent of this in a pure JavaScript structure? This sends values to the server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This script is designed to get the values from the inputs and send it by ajax to x.php as POST data to be echo by x.php. This works perfectly but I want to convert

this jQuery structure to a pure JavaScript structure so in other words how can I send a basic JS Object contents as POST data by AJAX to be echo by x.php

**jQuery structure(works*)**

**index.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#send').click(function(){
//Var structure
var first_name= $('#first_name').val();
var last_name= $('#last_name').val();

//Data var
var data={
      first_name: first_name,
      last_name: last_name
}


//Success var
var success= function(response){
   $('.output-container').html(response);
}

//Request
    $.ajax({
      data: data,
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'x',
      success: success
    });
  });
});

</script>

<input id='first_name' type='text' value='John'>
<input id='last_name' type='text' value='Doe'>

<button id='send'>Send</button>

<div class='output-container'><div>
```

**JavaScript structure(Failed attempt*)**

**index.php**

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

var execute_sendAjax = document.getElementById('send');
  execute_sendAjax.addEventListener("click", executeAjax);

var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        document.getElementsByClassName('output-container')[0].innerHTML= xhr.responseText;
    }
};

function executeAjax(){

  //Var structrue
  var first_name=  document.getElementById('first_name').value;
  var last_name=  document.getElementById('last_name').value;

//Data var
var data={
  first_name: first_name,
  last_name: last_name
}

    xhr.open('POST','x');
    xhr.send();
}
});
</script>

<input id='first_name' type='text' value='John'>
<input id='last_name' type='text' value='Doe'>

<button id='send'>Send</button>

<div class='output-container'><div>
```

**x.php**

```
<?php

$first_name=$_POST['first_name'];
$last_name=$_POST['last_name'];

?>

<h1><?php echo $first_name; ?></h1>
</h1><?php echo $last_name; ?></h1>
```

In the pure JS structure I don't know where to go from there that's where I'm getting stuck at.

**Recent findings UPDATED***

After doing some more research([Link](http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Ajax-Post-to-PHP-File-XMLHttpRequest-Object-Return-Data-Tutorial)) I found out that *application/x-www-form-urlencoded* is another way to encode as POST data but I had to avoid using a JS object because it does not work with a normal JS object. I'm still looking for a way that I can use as a JS object.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){

var execute_sendAjax = document.getElementById('send');
  execute_sendAjax.addEventListener("click", executeAjax);

var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        document.getElementsByClassName('output-container')[0].innerHTML= xhr.responseText;
    }
};

function executeAjax(){

  //Var structrue
  var first_name=  document.getElementById('first_name').value;
  var last_name=  document.getElementById('last_name').value;

//Data var
var data = "first_name="+first_name+"&last_name="+last_name;

/*var data={
  first_name: first_name,
  last_name: last_name
}*/

    xhr.open('POST','x');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //<--I notice this makes it encoded to be used as POST data
    xhr.send(data);
}
});
</script>

<input id='first_name' type='text' value='John'>
<input id='last_name' type='text' value='Doe'>

<button id='send'>Send</button>

<div class='output-container'><div>
```

Comment: You’re not passing the data to the server. It should be xhr.send(data);

Comment: I added that data var to xhr.send(data); as you instructed but x.php is not getting the values at all so it results x.php to output these errors ...Undefined index: first_name  .... Undefined index: last_name ...

Comment: Also needs to be xhr.open(‘POST’, ‘x.php’);

Comment: Same results :..(

Comment: Have you tried looking at your browser’s dev tools to see what the request and response looks like?

Comment: Yes in the chrome Dev tools browser the jQuery version of this is recognizing this as form data which shows John Doe and the JS version is being recognize as Request Payload

[object object]

Comment: Set the content-type header to application/json and use JSON.stringify on data will send it, but I believe php will need you to send it as form data to use _POST

Comment: Well i'm aware of JSON and I know that is a option that I can use in jQuery and JS as well but what is the equivalent of that jQuery example of that I provided above? Obviously it isn't using JSON then what's under the hood of that jQuery example that is able to do that obviously it must be possible with a normal JS object in the JS example I provided the question is how?

Comment: This is an experiment that I am doing to convert that jQuery example into a pure JS example as close as possible. I'm just saying I'm trying to avoid JSON because that jQuery example above isn't using JSON at all.

Comment: I wonder what jQuery is using to be able to do that? I wish I knew.

Comment: See my answer below for example.

Comment: Btw, you can look at the JQuery code if you want to see exactly what they are doing https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js

Answer (score 0):

JQuery is marshaling the Javascript object into form data. There are lots of ways to do this, but I think the easiest way is to use a `FormData` object like so:

```
function executeAjax(){
    var data = new FormData();
    // FormData.append(name, value) - appends a new value onto an 
    //  existing key inside a FormData object, or adds the key if 
    //  it does not already exist.
    data.append("first_name", document.getElementById('first_name').value;);
    data.append("last_name", document.getElementById('last_name').value;


    xhr.open('POST','x.php');
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

Then you don't have to edit any PHP or set the content-type in the request header.

If you don't like the `FormData` object (for whatever reason):

```
function executeAjax(data) {
    var data = [
        "first_name="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('first_name').value),
        "last_name="+encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('last_name').value)
    ].join('&').replace(/%20/g, '+');

    xhr.open('POST', 'x.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(data);
}
```

Learn more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript).

Sorry was not at the computer before.

Comment: Thank you @Popmedic that was going to be my next question in another future post that I was going to ask, Since I know how I can do that in jQuery with the formData() you just showed me how I can use the formData() in JS so I thank you for that answer to that future post. I just updated the post of my new findings, In other words I found out you can also use "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" to encode into a POST structure. But i'm still looking to find a way how I can do this with a plain JS object. Sadly no solutions on how I can do that :( but I feel like i'm getting close

Comment: I am not really sure I understand, what do you mean "plain JS object"? You will have to marshal it somehow... Either as a string in JSON encoding or encoded as FormData, but it has to be marshaled... Like I say JQuery is marshalling it for you as FormData.  So it is under the covers converting it to form data, but HTTP POST requests need it to be marshaled to something it can send, it can not send a raw Javascript object.  The closest would be JSON, but then you have to read it in on the PHP side, it will not be in the $_POST var.

Comment: You do realize an Ajax request is sending data over HTTP, and HTTP is not Javascript, so you have to marshal(encode) it to fit the hyper-text transfer protocol.  One way is to encode it to an HTTP defined encoding called form data, like JQuery is doing.  On the PHP side it will unmarshal(decode) the form data under the covers for you into the $_POST vars.